# Clear cache of UIL library

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using universal image loader library for loading the images in my listview. I want to clear the cache for all the images at once.

I know how to do it for one image at a time.

```
 MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache("file://"+path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache("file://"+path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by:

```
imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
```

or

```
imageLoader.getDiskCache().clear();
```

it depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the memory cache and the disk cache distinctly. For each just call:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache();
ImageLoader.getInstance().clearDiskCache();
```

It will erase all stored cache data.